# Example of two modules M, N where the set of the $m\otimes n$ is not a submodule

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products, tensors

If I remember my Algebra class correctly, this is in general not true because, for example, the addition isn't closed. So if I take:

$B:\mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^{2^2}\cong \mathbb{R}^2 \otimes \mathbb{R}^2$

$(m,n)\mapsto mn^t$

The Image of B isn't closed under Addition since the resulting Matrix of B(m,n) has either Rank 1 or 2.

Is this correct, or am I making a mistake along the way?

Comment: Yes - the resulting matrix has rank $0$ or $1$, so in particular no matrix of rank $2$ is in the image.